# Publishing vNext project to Windows Server 2016 Preview Container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, windows-server

I'm trying to publish my vNext project to one of the new windows containers for docker that's in Windows Server 2016 Preview 3.  I've installed the container feature and created a container, and also mapped port 80 from host to container.  Only thing is now I'm stuck as to how I'm actually supposed to publish from Visual Studio using the Visual Studio Tools for Docker.

[image]

Any ideas how to proceed from here?

Comment: Try port 2376

`tcp://192.168.15.4:2376`

Answer (score 0):

Nick,
You should use the port number on which Docker daemon is listening. Port 80 will be used to accessing the application which you will host inside the container.

Comment: I got it working in the end by modifying the startup script for docker so that it binds to the LAN IP and doesn't have TLS enabled.  It wasn't able to connect as I needed to be on the same IP.  Purely for testing of course so I understand that it's not secure that way.